# My BAT file does not execute my executable file

Tags: batch-file

I have a code witch I want to starts when windows starts so I added bat file in

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

directory and my bat file is like:

```
start "random title" "C:\test\dist\test.exe"
```

this code works when I use it in cmd but in bat it only shows terminal for like 0.01 second then it close itself without run my code I have added `cmd.exe` at the end of my code just to see the error log but did not worked
then tried `pause` `cmd-k` and other solutions

any idea would be very usefull

also I am searching this for days so I guess I have checked every source I could find so this question seems like dublicate but other questions did not solved my problem

Comment: Usually, there is no need to use `start` to start a program from batch (unless you have special needs). Just `"C:\test\dist\test.exe"` should do fine.

Comment: You don't need a batch file, all you need to do is to create a shortcut to `"C:\test\dist\test.exe"` in `"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day I ended up with creating a shortcut as Compo said here is my code:

```
path = os.path.join(bat_path, 'windowsStartup.lnk')
target = file_path

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.WindowStyle = 1
shortcut.save()
```